# Как через ТГ бота ответить на сообщение пользователя?

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telebot

Доброго времени суток.

Допустим, у меня есть пару сообщение отправленных мне через бота от разных пользователей. И я хочу,  выделить одно из них(с помощью reply в самом телеграмме) и ответить только на него. И мой ответ бы переслался пользователю, который задал мне этот вопрос.

Но как данную задачу реализовать с помощью кода python??

Answer (score 0):

```py
@bot.message_handler(func=lambda message: message.reply_to_message != None)
def reply_message_handler(message):
    bot.send_message(chat_id=message.reply_to_message.from_user.id, text=message.text)
```